# How do sentences like 'he is said to' work?

Tags: passive-voice

1. People say that he steals motorcycles -> He is said by people to steal motorcycles
2. People say that he will steal motorcycles -> He is said by people to steal motorcycles
3. People say that he stole motorcycles -> He is said by people to have stolen motorcycles
4. People say that he is stealing motorcycles -> He is said by people to be stealing motorcycles
5. People say that he will be stealing motorcycles -> He is said by people to be stealing motorcycles
6. People say that he was stealing motorcycles -> He is said by people to have been stealing
7. People say that he has stolen motorcycles -> He is said by people to have stolen motorcycles
8. People say that he will have stolen motorcycles by New Year's Eve -> He is said by people to have stolen motorcycles by New Year's Eve
9. People say that he had stolen motorcycles by the time police arrived -> He is said by people to have stolen motorcycles by the time police arrived
10. People say that he has been stealing motorcycles -> He is said by people to have been stealing motorcycles
11. People say that he will have been stealing motorcycles by New Year's Eve -> He is said by people to have been stealing motorcycles by New Year's Eve
12. People say that he had been stealing motorcycles by the time police arrived -> He is said by people to have been stealing motorcycles by the time police arrived

Are there any rules that specify how the infinitive "TO ..." changes?

Also, I could replace "people say" with "people said" or "people will say" or "people has said." or even more crazier versions. What happens then?

EDIT:
In order to correctly form the infinitive you need to take into account both verbs in the input sentence.

People SAY that he STOLE motorcycles -> He is said by people TO HAVE STOLEN motorcycles

People SAY that he STEALS motorcycles -> He is said by people TO STEAL motorcycles

People SAID that he STOLE motorcycles -> He was said by people TO STEAL motorcycles

How does it work?

Comment: I don't think "He is said by people to have stolen motorcycles by New Year's Eve" is actually equivalent to "People say that he will have stolen motorcycles by New Year's Eve." Only the latter is idiomatic when referring to future time.

Comment: @alphabet You could be right. It's quite likely.

Comment: All the transformed examples you gave are strictly grammatical, but the natural way to say them is without 'by people'. I'm not sure exactly what you're asking for though.

Comment: @Mitch I asked for the rules of how such transformations work.

Comment: This question is too confusing. You might want to pare it down.

Comment: @Lambie When you have the sentence "People say that he steals motorcycles" you can change it to "He is said by people to steal motorcycles" without changing the meaning.  But how do you do that? In particular, how do you know what form of infinitive to use? Should I use "to steal" or "to have stolen" or maybe "to have been stealing"?

Comment: You just use the verb you used in the active sentence....my eyes are glazing over but THIS: 11) People say that he will have stolen motorcycles by New Year's Eve -> is incorrect.  ***It is said by people** that he will have stolen motorcycles by NYE.  You can't use "He is said by people".

Comment: @Lambie I understand that everyone agrees that I can't transform sentences with "will" but that doesn't exhaust the topic. Notice that you have TWO verbs in the active sentence. "People say" and "he steals". I can change tenses in both of these verbs. I wonder how this affects the type of infinitive in the passive sentence

Comment: @Lambie To correctly form the infinitive in the passive sentence, I have to take into account BOTH verbs in the active sentence. "People say that he stole motorcycles -> He is said by people to have stolen motorcycles". Now I'll change only the second verb in active side. "People say that he steals motorcycles -> He is said by people to steal motorcycles". The infinitive has changed. Now I'll change only the first verb in active voice. "People said that he stole motorcycles -> He was said by people to steal motorcycles" The infinitive has also changed.

Comment: The first verb is not relevant because you repeat "He is said by people" 11 times. This is the last time I will try to help you.

Comment: @Lambie But after all I wrote in the post (before any editing): "Also, I could replace "people say" with "people said" or "people will say" or "people has said." or even more crazier versions. What happens then?" Should I have written 50 more sentences? I don't think so.

Comment: You already had too many. The problem is that no one uses these extremely awkward sentences. If you say: He is said to x, you don't need "by people", because who else would it be? I'm done here.

Comment: @Lambie "by people" Is completely irrelevant. We are talking about the GRAMMATICAL STRUCTURE here so it doesn't matter if you add "be people" or not. It doesn't matter if you talk about motorcycles or pink whales.

Answer (score 1):

You are showing “impersonal passives” for active voice constructions that use reporting verbs (warning: grammar terms vary).

(By the way, we use the impersonal passive when we want to be, well, impersonal, thus we would normally omit the *by*-phrase agent: *He is said <del>[by people]</del> to steal motorcycles*.)

There are two ways to render an impersonal passive:

> Active: *People say that he steals motorcycles.*
>  Passive: *He is
> said to steal motorcycles.*
>  Passive: *It is said that he steals
> motorcycles.*

Only the second of these passive forms will work when there’s a modal (such as *will*) in the *that*-clause. So your examples at (2), (5), (8), and (11) don’t work as you’ve shown them. Try instead:

> (2) *People say that he will steal motorcycles.* -> *It is said that
> he will steal motorcycles.*
>
> (5) *People say that he will be stealing motorcycles.* -> *It is said
> that he will be stealing motorcycles.*
>
> (8) *People say that he will have stolen motorcycles by New Year’s
> Eve.* -> *It is said that he will have stolen motorcycles by New
> Year’s Eve.*
>
> (11) *People say that he will have been stealing motorcycles by New
> Year’s Eve.* -> *It is said that he will have been stealing
> motorcycles by New Year’s Eve.*

Also, yes, you can replace *people say* with *people said* or *people will say* or *people have said* — just follow the above, paying attention to the *that*-clause . . .

Both forms work here:

> *People said that he steals motorcycles.* -> *He was said to steal motorcycles.* / *It was said that he steals motorcycles.*
> *People will say that he steals motorcycles.* -> *He will be said to steal motorcycles.* / *It will be said that he steals motorcycles.*
> *People have said that he steals motorcycles.* -> *He has been said to steal motorcycles.* / *It has been said that he steals motorcycles.*

But only the *it*-form works here:

> *People said that he will steal motorcycles.* -> *It was said that he will steal motorcycles.*
> *People will say that he should steal motorcycles.* -> *It will be said that he should steal motorcycles.*
> *People have said that he might steal motorcycles.* -> *It has been said that he might steal motorcycles.*

<sub>See more at [Grammaring—Passive voice with reporting verbs](https://www.grammaring.com/passive-voice-with-reporting-verbs) and surrounding pages.</sub>

Comment: When I change "people say" to "people said", the forms of infinitives also change. Compare: 1. "People say that he stole motorcycles -> He is said by people to HAVE STOLEN motorcycles" 2. "People said that he stole motorcycles -> He was said by people TO STEAL motorcycles" How does it work?

Comment: 1. "People say [now] that he stole motorcycles [in the past]". 2. People said [in the past] that he stole motorcycles [at that time]."

Comment: @KateBunting I understand how it works in 'that clause' but I'm not sure how to represent it in ifinitives

Comment: I was paraphrasing your sentences with infinitives, to show you the reason for the difference in tense between the two.

Comment: I can't see any infinitives in your response. You didn't use "he is said to" at all. Sorry if I sound abrupt, I didn't mean to.

Comment: I understand the difference between "people say" vs "people said" and "he is said" vs "he was said". What I don't understand is how these differences affect an infinitive later in the sentence.

Comment: My guess is that it works similarly to 'sequence of tenses' but infinitives makes it difficult

Comment: It doesn’t affect the infinitive later in the sentence. *that he stole motorcycles* becomes *to have stolen motorcycles* for all. People say: *He is said to have stolen motorcycles.* People said: *He is said to have stolen motorcycles.* People have said: *He has been said to have stolen motorcycles.* People had said: *He had been said to have stolen motorcycles.*

Comment: @TinfoilHat So if it doesn't affect the infinitive, the second sentence is not an actually equivalent because "he stole" remains the same: 1. "People say that he stole motorcycles -> He is said by people to HAVE STOLEN motorcycles" 2. "People said that he stole motorcycles -> He was said by people TO STEAL motorcycles". It should be: 2. "People said that he stole motorcycles -> He was said by people TO HAVE STOLEN motorcycles"

Comment: I’m not sure what your saying. This is incorrect: *People said that he stole motorcycles* -> *He was said TO STEAL motorcycles*, and this is correct: *People said that he stole motorcycles* -> *He was said TO HAVE STOLEN motorcycles.*

Comment: @TinfoilHat So it does affect the infinitive later in the sentence. Now my question: how does changing "People say/said/will say" change the infinitive in the second sentence?

Comment: 1. "People say that he stole motorcycles -> He is said by people to HAVE STOLEN motorcycles" 2. "People said that he stole motorcycles -> He was said by people TO STEAL motorcycles" How does it work?

Comment: My guess is that it works similarly to 'sequence of tenses' but infinitives makes it difficult

Answer (score 0):

(One note: strictly speaking, "he has stolen motorcycles" is ambiguous; it could be a present perfect verb, or it could mean "he possesses stolen motorcycles." I'll assume you intend the former interpretation, which asserts that he himself is the thief.)

*Say* is a rather unusual verb, in that it is often used with an infinitive in the passive voice, but not in the active voice. This is unlike the verb *tell,* which (in the sense of "order") takes an infinitive in either voice, as in "I told him to leave" and "He was told to leave." That said, there are no special rules regarding the aspect of the infinitive that comes after *say*; in that regard it works the same way as *tell.*

First, the infinitive form of *steal* is *to steal,* that of the perfect marker *have* is *to have*, and that of the progressive marker *is* is *to be.* That suffices to explain your examples (1), (4), (7), and (10).

Now, perfect infinitives are not subject to the same constraints as present perfects, since there are no "past tense infinitives" for them to contrast with (Huddleston & Pullum (2002)). So, when a past tense finite verb turns into an infinitive, it becomes a perfect infinitive. This explains your examples (3) and (6).

As mentioned above, we can turn "People say that he *stole* motorcycles into "People say that he has *stolen* motorcycles," since *stolen* is the past participle form of *to steal.* Likewise, when *have* means "possess," it's past participle form is *had,* so we can say "People say that he had cool motorcycles before the incident" into "He is said to have had cool motorcycles." But when *have* is used as a marker of the perfect, it lacks a past participle form. So we can't turn "People say that he had stolen motorcycles" into *"He is said to have had stolen motorcycles" (unless we reinterpret "have" as meaning "possesses"). Instead we just use the ordinary perfect; this explains your examples (9) and (12).

Now, when *will* is used as an ordinary lexical verb, as in "People say that he wills himself to steal motorcycles," its infinitive form is *will,* so we can transform that into "He is said to will himself to steal motorcycles." But when *will* is used as a modal auxiliary verb, it doesn't have an infinitive form. So we can't transform "People say that he will steal motorcycles" into *"He is said to will steal motorcycles." Instead, we have to use something like "He is said to be going/planning/about to steal motorcycles." This is the more idiomatic way of using the infinitive in (5), (8), and (12); I don't think most would accept "He is said by people to steal motorcycles" as an equivalent of "People say that he will steal motorcycles."

> Also, I could replace "people say" with "people said" or "people will say" or "people has said." or even more crazier versions. What happens then?

This answer is long enough as it is, but in general, whereas a sentence starting with "People say that he" turns into a sentence starting with "He is said by people to," a sentence starting with "People said that he" or "People will say that he" will turn into one starting with "He was said by people to" or "He will be said by people to," respectively.

Comment: So in other words. When we start with "people say": 1. will - no direct form 2. perfect/past continuous tenses - to have been + ...ing 3. perfect/past tenses - to have + past particple  4. continuous tenses - to be + ...ing

Comment: Also as to the last part of your statement. Yes "People said that he" -> "he was said by people to" but the forms of infinitives also change. Compare: 1. "People say that he stole motorcycles -> He is said by people to HAVE STOLEN motorcycles" 2. "People said that he stole motorcycles -> He was said by people TO STEAL motorcycles" How does it work?

Comment: My guess is that it works similarly to 'sequence of tenses' but infinitives makes it difficult

Comment: It's ambiguous. It's not an affine transformation in geometry. You can't just expect to shift some of the tenses and preserve the exact meaning without any further clarifications or other changes. How you use tenses depends on the precise sequence of events; it works differently in past and present; and information about precise ordering may not always be present in the original sentence (just as with any other process of translation, information can be lost or you may have to guess at meanings to fill in uncertainties). Solution: write prose, don't manipulate it like code.